# There is a way to integrate R with forms?

Tags: r

It seems that the googleformsr package is outdated, I couldn't do anything with it, is there any way to integrate R with some forms?

```
library(googleformr)
html=get_form("url")
>get_form_questions(html)
character(0)
```